# Print char of roman numeral for 10000

Tags: java

I've searched and cannot seem to find the unicode number relating to roman numerals for Java's unicode char.

Is there anyway to `System.out.print()` the following roman numerals?

[image]

Comment: Use the combining overline `\u0305`

Comment: If you would like to copy the characters: V̅ X̅ L̅ C̅ D̅ M̅

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the unicode `"\u0305"` which is the combining overline. So for 5000, you can do `System.out.println("V\u0305")`. For 10000, `System.out.println("X\u0305")`, etc.

Comment: hmm, this prints out the following "V" with a trailing overline in the intellij compiler output. However, when I copy and paste it into here, it prints as the following "V̅". Any idea why this is?

Comment: It's printing out "V̅" for me. Check it out [here](https://repl.it/EHVN).

Comment: sorry, didn't mean to post comment above before I could get the full wording out. Didn't know "enter" is hot keyed to add comment.

Comment: @FiddleFreak Probably IntelliJ has a weird compiler output. It should be V̅ not V ̅

Comment: Okay, I guess that is for another question to be answered. Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to create a map from decimal numbers to roman numerals

```
Map<Integer, String> table = new HashMap<>();
table.put(1, "I");
table.put(5, "V");
table.put("10", "X");
```

so on and so forth. You only need to create mapping for each special number, for example, 1, 5, 10, 100,... because the other numbers are derived from these special numbers for example, 1 is I, 2 is II, 10 is X, 11 is XI. You get the idea.

Comment: Not what OP is asking for.